# In a (html, css) container with an image, a heading and a description; why won't the description start right below the heading?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a container with an image, a heading and a description but the description starts below the heading as if I had inserted a `<br>` element after the heading. Here's the code and the example:

```
h6 {color: rgb(0,0,0,0.9);
        font: 1.5em Tahoma, Arial;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;}      /*article heading*/

.wc {background-color: #F9F9F9;
        max-width: 1024px;
        height: 180px;
        overflow: clip;}        /*windows container*/
.wc img {width: 300px;
                height: 180px;
                float: left;
                margin-right: 5px;}

.dsc {color: rgb(0,0,0,0.7);
         font: 1.3em Calibri, Arial;}       /*description*/
```

html:

```
<div class="wc">
    <img src="win11" alt="Error loading image">
    <h6>How to solve "Setup was unable to create a new system partition 
or locate an existing one" error when installing Windows</h6>
    <span class="dsc">In less than 3 minutes, you can encounter one
 of the most bizzare and annoying errors to occur when installing
 Windows on a machine. It usually occurs when re-installing Windows,
 even if you try a clean install.</span>
```

Here's the result:
[image: the result I'm getting]

I tried it with `<p>` and `<span>` elements. Also, I want the description overflow to clip and leave a '...' behind rather than clip on one's face.

Comment: That's because `<h6>` has `display: block;`, and `block` elements occupy the full-width of their container.

Comment: `alt="Error loading image"` <-- This is **not** what the `alt=""` attribute is for.

Comment: Wow, two comments, detailed answer, Thanks. About the alt attribute, w3schools told me so, I am learning from them.

Comment: Oooh, okay, just looked up alt attribute again, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heading tags contain margins by default, separating them from other elements. You can remove the margin so the text is closer together.

```css
h6 {
  margin: 0;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  font: 1.5em Tahoma, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
}


/*article heading*/

.wc {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  max-width: 1024px;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: clip;
}


/*windows container*/

.wc img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.dsc {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  font: 1.3em Calibri, Arial;
}


/*description*/
```

```html
<div class="wc">
  <img src="win11" alt="Error loading image">
  <h6>How to solve "Setup was unable to create a new system partition or locate an existing one" error when installing Windows</h6>
  <span class="dsc">In less than 3 minutes, you can encounter one
 of the most bizzare and annoying errors to occur when installing
 Windows on a machine. It usually occurs when re-installing Windows,
 even if you try a clean install.</span>
```

Comment: Thankyou very much. Also, reffering to my second question within description of first question. For longer descriptions, I want the over flow to end with a '...' instead of just cutting through. How to do it?